# Reading properties from a file in Java Spring

Tags: java, spring

I'm new to Java/Spring and tried to read properties from a file. This is what I did so far.

`Controller.java` launches the application:

```
import org.springframework.boot.*;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.*;

@EnableAutoConfiguration
public class Controller {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        SpringApplication.run(Controller.class, args);
        Test test = new Test();
        test.doWork();
    }

}
```

This calls the doWork() method of `Test.java`:

```
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Value;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.EnableAutoConfiguration;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.PropertySource;

@EnableAutoConfiguration
@PropertySource("application.properties")
public class Test {

    @Value("${db.password}")
    private String dbPassword;

    public void doWork() {
        System.out.println(dbPassword);
    }

}
```

I put some properties in `application.properties`:

```
db.password=Snap&Fudge!
```

The file structure of the project looks like this:

```
./pom.xml
./src/main/java/Controller.java
./src/main/java/Test.java
./src/main/resources/application.properties
```

When I run the application, I see that `Test.doWork()` is run, but instead of printing out the property, it returns `null`.

Can you see what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You are creating a new instance of test yourself instead of using a spring managed instance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are creating a new instance of test yourself instead of using a spring managed instance.

First change your `Controller` class.

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Controller {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        ApplicationContext ctx = SpringApplication.run(Controller.class, args);
        Test test = ctx.getBean(Test.class);
        test.doWork();
    }
}
```

Next change your `Test` class.

```
@Component 
public class Test {

    @Value("${db.password}")
    private String dbPassword;

    public void doWork() {
        System.out.println(dbPassword);
    }

}
```

Now you will have a Spring managed (and configured) instance of the `Test` class, which you get from the `ApplicationContext`.